# Problems with browser refresh with input fields?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a webpage with a simple list of tasks that I'm pulling out of a SQL-db. Together with this list I have an simple ordinary input field, where I can add some new tasks to the list in SQL. All standard with a few textfields, and a "Add" button, that sends me to the "handler.php", where I grab the data and stuff into the db. So far so good.

in the handler I just stuff the data into the db and then do a ordinary php "header()" call back to the list.

My problem is with the update of the list. When I enter the data into the fields and tab myself through it and complete the data input with a press on the key "ENTER", everything works just fine.

BUT, if I enter the data into the fields and the "CLICK" on the button with the mouse, or even tab myself to the button and hit ENTER, I get back to the list but the latest db-entry isn't pulled from the db?

I can force the browser to reload (Ctrl-F5) and it pulls out the new data, but I want this to happend automatically, just as if I were hitting ENTER in the input field.

My simple form

```
<form name ="frm_todo" method="get" action="handle_verification.php">
    <table><tr>
      <td align="right">Date </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input size="20" type="date" name="inp_date"/></td>
    </tr></table>
    <input type="submit" name="{$submitString}" value="{$submitValue}"/>
</form>
```

And this is a little bit of the handler-code (I remove a chunk of pre-processing code.

```
$qry = "INSERT INTO verification (v_date) ";
$qry .= "VALUES ('$db_date')";
$res = mysql_query( $qry, $g_dbh) or die ("Failed!".  mysql_error());
header('Location: http://www.backtolist.com/mylist.php');
exit();
```

Well, here's a shortened version of my loop for getting the list from the db where I'v removed alot of the processing stuff to keep it short, hope u get the picture.

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM verification ORDER BY v_date ASC $limit";
$result_id = mysql_query($qry, $global_dbh) or die("Error --->".mysql_error());

$tableStr = get_tableHeader();
$tableStr .= '<tbody>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_id)) {
    // some processing/formatting
    $tableStr .= '<tr><td>'.$id.'</td><td>'.$date.'</td><td>'.$desc.'</td>';     
    $tableStr .= '</tr>';
}
$tableStr .= '</tbody></table>';
echo $tableStr;
```

Is there any explanation for this behaviour, or any pointers to what I might have done wrong?

Thnx in advance,
Humble
(Update with some code, and made some clarifications, sry)

Comment: Can you post some pieces of code please ?

Comment: Have you tried different browsers and still get the same result? Do you use any javascript? Will your example code still result in the same behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably that the default action of the input field will cause the site to refresh.
You can use

```
$('#submit').addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    handleData();
    return false;
}, false);
```

to prevent that from happening and then call the function to handle your data.